# Ubuntu 16.04 excessive disk activity

Tags: ubuntu, cinnamon

I recently upgraded my laptop from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. Mostly due to Cinnamon becoming unstable. I did a clean install of Ubunutu 16.04 with cinnamon. I have noticed that my SSD disk is constantly "Busy",

```
sudo iotop
```

I can see that `cinnamon --replace is running constantly`

```
System:    Host: avrono-K55VD Kernel: 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.0.7 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1)
           Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: ASUSTeK (portable) product: K55VD v: 1.0
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: K55VD v: 1.0
           Bios: American Megatrends v: K55VD.404 date: 08/20/2012
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-3210M (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 9977
           clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 1966 MHz 2: 1908 MHz 3: 2315 MHz
           4: 2044 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
           bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF119M [GeForce 610M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) FAILED: nouveau
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.01hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel 7 Series/C210 Series Family High Definition     Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-47-    generic
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: ath9k bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus-ID: 04:00.2
           IF: enp4s0f2 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 250.1GB (66.1% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: Samsung_SSD_840 size: 250.1GB temp: 0C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 221G used: 147G (70%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
          ID-2: swap-1 size: 8.47GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda3
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 57.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 50.0
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 2600
Info:      Processes: 270 Uptime: 12 min Memory: 4035.1/7869.4MB
          Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
          Client: Shell (bash 4.3.461) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Any suggestions ?